# The binding of 'routerLink' and 'fragment' directives doesn't work

Tags: angular, binding, routes, navigation

I am trying to bind a JS object to the html template to display some nav links to no avail. If I hardcode the same information in the html the links work.

component.ts

```
  navigation = [
    { link: '/home', label: 'Home', fragment: null },
    { link: '/home', label: 'Get Your Number!', fragment: 'get-your-number' },
    { link: '/home', label: 'Pricing', fragment: 'pricing' },
    { link: '/contact-us', label: 'Contact Us', fragment: null },
    { link: '/signin', label: 'Sign In', fragment: null },
  ];
```

component.html

```
            <button
              mat-button
              *ngFor="let item of navigation"
              [routerLink]="[item.link]"
              [fragment]="[item.fragment]"
              routerLinkActive="active"
            >
              {{ item.label }}
            </button>
```

Hard-coded version in the template works:

```
<button mat-button routerLink="/home" fragment="pricing" routerLinkActive="active">
```

Answer (score 1):

try this: change

`[routerLink]="[item.link]" [fragment]="[item.fragment]"`
`

to

`[routerLink]="item.link" [fragment]="item.fragment"`